# How-to find non existing ids in Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore collection with many documents.

I receive from another system, a list of (8000) ids, and I need to create new Firestore documents when some ids are missing.

How can I query my Firestore collection to get only missing ids from given list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore does not have any way to query for data that does not exist.  All queries must use an index, and it's not reasonable to maintain an index for all values that could not exist - that data set is infinitely large.

The only way you can find out if a specific document ID does not exist is to query for it and see that the query returns no documents.  In your case, you're going to execute about 8000 document gets in order to fully gather the data you need.